# Applying Validations into arrays

Tags: c#

I was just wondering how could I apply validation that accepts int only into this code, I'm new to this so not familiar with c#.

```
Console.Write("Please enter the number of tickets sold for Adult:(100 for exit)");

int adultTickets = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

while (adultTickets == 100)
{

Console.WriteLine("Good Bye");

Environment.Exit(0);

}
Console.Write("Please enter the number of tickets sold for child:(100 for exit)");

int childTickets = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

while (childTickets == 100)

{

Console.WriteLine("Good Bye");

Environment.Exit(0);

}

int[] arrAmt = new int[] { 30, 20 };

int[] tickets = new int[] { adultTickets, childTickets };

int totalCost = 0;

if (tickets[0] >= 5 && tickets[0] <= 30)

{

totalCost += tickets[0] * arrAmt[0];

Console.Write("The sale amount of tickets for Adult: ${0} \n", (arrAmt[0] * tickets[0]));

}

else

{

Console.Write("Not Valid \n");

}

if (tickets[1] >= 5 && tickets[1] <= 30)

{

totalCost += tickets[1] * arrAmt[1];

Console.Write("The sale amount of tickets for child: ${0} \n", (arrAmt[1] * tickets[1]));

}

Console.WriteLine("The total sale amount: {0}", totalCost);
```

Comment: i have no idea how to apply the code below into my own, I'm really new to this, someone from more direct guidance. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private static bool GetNumberFromConsole()
    {
        bool isValid = false;
        int input = -1;
        while (!isValid)
            if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out input))
                isValid = true;
            else
                Console.WriteLine("not a number");

        Console.WriteLine("number entered:" + input);
        return isValid;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that this code could use a lot of compaction and generalization, but this is an idea to do what you want using int.tryparse():

```
 public void calculate_Tickets()
    {
        int adult = adult_Tickets();
        int child = child_Tickets();
        ticket_Prices(adult, child);
    }
    private int adult_Tickets()
    {
        Console.Write("Please enter the number of tickets sold for Adult:(100 for exit)");

        int adultTickets = 0;
        if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(),out adultTickets)){

            if (adultTickets == 100)
            {

                Console.WriteLine("Good Bye");

                Environment.Exit(0);

            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("you may only inter numbers");
                adult_Tickets();
            }

        }
        return adultTickets;
    }
    private int child_Tickets() {

        Console.Write("Please enter the number of tickets sold for child:(100 for exit)");

        int childTickets = 0;
        if (int.TryParse((Console.ReadLine(), out childTickets)){

            if (childTickets == 100)

            {

                Console.WriteLine("Good Bye");

                Environment.Exit(0);

            }
        } else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("you may only inter numbers");
            child_Tickets();
        }
        return childTickets;
    }
    private void ticket_Prices(int adultTickets, int childTickets) {
        int[] arrAmt = new int[] { 30, 20 };

        int[] tickets = new int[] { adultTickets, childTickets };

        int totalCost = 0;

        if (tickets[0] >= 5 && tickets[0] <= 30)

        {

            totalCost += tickets[0] * arrAmt[0];

            Console.Write("The sale amount of tickets for Adult: ${0} \n", (arrAmt[0] * tickets[0]));

        }

        else

        {

            Console.Write("Not Valid \n");

        }

        if (tickets[1] >= 5 && tickets[1] <= 30)

        {

            totalCost += tickets[1] * arrAmt[1];

            Console.Write("The sale amount of tickets for child: ${0} \n", (arrAmt[1] * tickets[1]));

        }

        Console.WriteLine("The total sale amount: {0}", totalCost);

    }
```

Comment: Is it possible to do everything within the main?

Comment: It doesn't make a whole lot of sense to do it that way given that the user may enter invalid entries more than once. Keeping it as close to your original code as possible (again, a lot of optimization could happen), doing it in one method might look like:

Answer (score 0):

In one method (again a lot of optimization is necessary - this is trying to stay as close as possible to your original code):

```
private void doTickets()
    {
        AdultTix:
        Console.Write("Please enter the number of tickets sold for Adult:(100 for exit)");
        int adultTickets = 0;
        while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out adultTickets))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You may only enter numbers");
            Console.ReadLine();
            if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out adultTickets))
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        if (adultTickets == 100)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Good Bye");
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }
        if (adultTickets > 0 && (adultTickets < 5 || adultTickets > 30))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You may only purchase between 5 and 30 adult tickets. You tried to purchase " + adultTickets.ToString() + ". Please try again.");
            goto AdultTix;
        }
        ChildTix:
        Console.Write("Please enter the number of tickets sold for Child:(100 for exit)");
        int childTickets = 0;
        while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out childTickets))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You may only enter numbers");
            Console.ReadLine();
            if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out childTickets))
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        if (childTickets == 100)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Good Bye");
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }
        if (childTickets > 0 && (childTickets < 5 || childTickets > 30))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You may only purchase between 5 and 30 child tickets. You tried to purchase " + childTickets.ToString() + ". Please try again.");
            goto ChildTix;
        }


        int[] arrAmt = new int[] { 30, 20 };

        int[] tickets = new int[] { adultTickets, childTickets };

        int totalCost = 0;


        totalCost += tickets[0] * arrAmt[0];

        Console.Write("The sale amount of tickets for Adult: ${0} \n", (arrAmt[0] * tickets[0]));




        totalCost += tickets[1] * arrAmt[1];

        Console.Write("The sale amount of tickets for child: ${0} \n", (arrAmt[1] * tickets[1]));


        Console.WriteLine("The total sale amount: {0}", totalCost);
    }
```